# No i2c nodes coming in linux sysfs, required kernel configs?

Tags: linux-kernel, config, i2c

I have a Hikey LeMaker 620 on which I am trying to enable I2C as currently I am not getting /dev/i2c* nodes.

I am using the docs here : https://github.com/96boards/documentation/blob/master/consumer/hikey/hikey620/build/linux-kernel.md

I see that
I2C_DESIGNWARE_PLATFORM
I2C_CHARDEV

are already enabled, still I do not see anything in /sys/bus/i2c/devices/ and as a result my i2cdetect fails saying “/dev/i2c/0 : No such file or directory”

Are there any kernel configs which I am missing?

**EDIT**

Here are the dmesg logs

```
/ # dmesg | grep i2c
[    0.251154] i2c-core: driver [dummy] registered
[    0.284233] i2c-core: driver [pca953x] registered
[    0.286078] i2c-core: driver [sec_pmic] registered
[    0.287137] i2c_designware f7100000.i2c: could not find pctldev for node /soc/pinmux@f7010000/i2c0_pmx_func, deferring probe
[    0.287167] i2c_designware f7101000.i2c: could not find pctldev for node /soc/pinmux@f7010000/i2c1_pmx_func, deferring probe
[    0.287188] i2c_designware f7102000.i2c: could not find pctldev for node /soc/pinmux@f7010000/i2c2_pmx_func, deferring probe
[    0.323590] i2c-core: driver [cs2000-cp] registered
[    0.328647] i2c-core: driver [fan53555-regulator] registered
[    0.340913] i2c-core: driver [cros-ec-i2c] registered
[    0.341005] i2c-core: driver [max77620] registered
[    0.341054] i2c-core: driver [rk808] registered
[    0.351637] i2c-core: driver [usb3503] registered
[    0.353610] i2c-core: driver [rtc-ds3232] registered
[    0.354842] i2c /dev entries driver
[    0.355782] i2c-core: driver [pca954x] registered
[    0.356294] i2c-core: driver [bq27xxx-battery] registered
[    0.501408] i2c-core: driver [hmc5843] registered
[    2.209817] i2c_designware f7100000.i2c: Unknown Synopsys component type: 0x00000000
[    2.218809] i2c_designware f7101000.i2c: Unknown Synopsys component type: 0x00000000
[    2.227621] i2c_designware f7102000.i2c: Unknown Synopsys component type: 0x00000000
```

Comment: There are quite a few things that could go wrong, and not much info to figure out what's happening here. Is there anything i2c related in kernel logs? In sysfs?

Comment: @domen : Please see the edit

Comment: Could be some pinmux configuration error, device tree error/mismatch, or just an issue with the driver. Quick web search of those errors doesn't seem to produce much here.  Hopefully someone with experience on this platform comes across this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a bug.
More discussion here : https://discuss.96boards.org/t/kernel-configuration-for-enabling-i2c-on-hikey-lemaker-620/7517